# Find out which IAM user created a given resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have multiple IAM users under my account. Is there a way to know which IAM user created a particular resource, such as an EC2 instance or an Elastic Search Cluster?

Comment: Here is a simple script which I use to list owner of EC2 Instances
https://gist.github.com/sudharsans/39d5eaf8a82b7ccdf8b3230d13ba7d81

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find this using cloudtrail. You can search for the relevant api actions on the console (for last 90 days) and search in the logs saved on S3 for api actions older than 90 days. Details [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-concepts.html#cloudtrail-concepts-console)

Answer (score 0):

There are 3-way Cloud trail, Cloud watch and Athena. follow the link below

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/view-iam-history/